# How to check if a button is pressed twice within 500 ms (PIC16)?

Tags: timer, pic

I have a switch button that is connected to RB1. This button acts as a reset but it needs to be pressed twice for it to work. If the second press happens after 500 ms (relative to the initial press), it will do nothing.

I think I should make use of timers or ccp module but I am not sure how to implement those. What do you suggest?

Edit (My ISR):

```
void interrupt ISR(void){
    GIE = 0;
    if(INTF){
        INTF = 0;
        if(reset_press == 0){
            TMR1 = 0x0BDC;              // counter starts counting at 0x0BDC (3036)
            TMR1ON = 1;                 // Turns on Timer1 (T1CON reg)
        }
        reset_press++;
    }
    else if(TMR1IF==1){                 // checks Timer1 interrupt flag 
        TMR1IF = 0;                     // clears interrupt flag
        if(reset_press == 2){
            reset_count();              // reset function
        }
        TMR1ON = 0;                     // Turns off Timer1 (T1CON reg)
        reset_press = 0; 
    }
    GIE = 1;
}
```

Comment: There many ways doing it. Depends on the exact device you are using.

Comment: @EliasSoares I am using PIC16F877A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Setup the timer or CCP for 500ms once in initialisation, but don't fire it. (You may have to use an additional byte to achive to hold a value that corresponds to 500ms depending on the osc freq).
- After you enter main's superloop, detect the button press; either use a flag or a counter to count the button press. As soon as you detect the first press,fire the 500ms timer.
- If the 500ms time has relapsed (you can detect it in the interrupts), that means that you will do nothing, so reset everything; button press counter, fired timer etc.
- Meanwhile before the 500ms has not been relapsed, if you detect a second press; that is the press counter value must be 2, then you execute what you wish and then reset everything for the next twice button press detection.

Comment: I did what you say and I think it should work but for some reason, my code doesn't work. Can you check my code? I edited my original post.

Comment: First you don't have to modify the GIE bit since when an interrupt occurs it is cleared automatically by hardware and set again when it return from interrupt.

Comment: Does TIM1 provides you 500mstime interval? What is the FOSC of your system?

Comment: One more thing when using mechanical switches; you better debounce the input because until we push the switch totally it will bounce and the INT interrupts will occur many times within 500 ms. In order to get a clean switch signal it is always better debouncing the switch.

Comment: I also see when you process `reset_press == 0` condition, you are not clearing the `TMR1F` flag prior to firing the timer. This may lead to false timer interrupts.

Comment: My FOSC is 4 Mhz. I am using `T1CON = 0X30;` and I cleared `TMR1IF` at the initialization of the program

Comment: Thank you for the help. I forgot to set `PEIE`.

Comment: @rickiestRick Have you managed to get it work?

Comment: Yes, setting the `PEIE` was the only thing missing.